# IF statement on ORDER BY returns only one value

Tags: mysql

thank you for your watching....

I want to get a set of rows that if col_3 in some condition and if the maximum value of col_1 is bigger than 5 than returns 4rows of col_1, col_2, col_3 order by col_1 and if the value is smaller than 5 than returns order by col_2

if max(col_1) >5

```
select col_1, col_2, col_3 from TABLE where col_3 = 'some condition' order by col_1  desc limit 4;
```

else

```
select col_1, col_2, col_3 from TABLE where col_3 = 'some condition' order by col_2  desc limit 4;
```

It works well apart, but next query returns only one row, ordered by col_2.

```
select col_1, col_2, col_3 from TABLE where col_3 = 'some condition' order by if(max(col_1) > 5, col_1, col_2)  desc limit 4;
```

Sorry for my short english...
Thank you for your help again
Have a nice day :)

Comment: [That's because `MAX` will group the result.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-maximum-column.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `(SELECT max(col_1) FROM TABLE) > 5` instead of `max(col_1) > 5`

```
select col_1, col_2, col_3 from TABLE where col_3 = 'some condition' order by if((SELECT max(col_1) FROM TABLE) > 5, col_1, col_2)  desc limit 4;
```

Comment: also note that with huge tables this query might not perform well, if you are using it with php or any other server side try to get count first and use it in your `ORDER BY IF` condition.